# silverlight XAP gets downloaded every time

Tags: silverlight, caching, xap

I've just uploaded my silverlight webpage to my production webserver. The issue im having is that everytime I open the website in the browser it is downloading a new copy of the XAP.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: I would really only want it to download a new copy of the xap when it is modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have seen a similar problem appear when we entered Daylight Savings Time (British Summer Time in the UK).

Check that the date/time on the server is not out of sync with the real world (usually by an hour). This may not be the cause of your problem, but best to check it anyway.